# Does Apple's Bonjour protocol work over cellular connections?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, nfc, bonjour

So here are the questions:

1. Does Apple's Bonjour even work over cellular (3G, 4G, LTE)?
2. If so, how local is the discovery? Discover all in the same cell tower? Same provider? The entire internet?

Also, just as a small side note, is there any Bonjour support on Android (libraries, OS, etc.).

Note: I'm really looking for a way to do local discovery, but iOS doesn't have a public Bluetooth API that could work with some droids (please correct me if I'm wrong, I really hope I am). I also read about Bonjour over Bluetooth, but I couldn't find any resources about it. Also, would NFC be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first two questions:

1. No; in theory, other subscribers on the same subnet could see each others' services, but AFAIK there's no provision for sending multicast packets over cellular networks. Even if there were, network providers would likely filter it to reduce bandwidth usage.
2. A Bonjour service is generally visible to any other device on the same link-local network, i.e. the same subnet, assuming that the router doesn't filter multicast packets. Most domestic routers relay them, but some large [e.g. college & corporate] networks drop them, again to reduce demand for bandwidth.

You can use [jMDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) to do Bonjour service advertising/discovery with Android, it's pretty mature (or you can even [roll your own](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-cheshire-dnsext-multicastdns/), it's not that difficult :)

As for Bluetooth and NFC, I'm not sure; it sounds like you'll need to administer some single point of registration/coordination for whatever service you're advertising/consuming.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I just have a few questions. About your last point, the thing is, I think bonjour over Bluetooth is the perfect thing, as it allows you to discover devices locally and then use IP-over-bluetooth to connect to them, I just can't find any documentation or examples. Do you know of any?

Comment: My understanding is that the mDNS responder in iOS will advertise Bonjour services over any supported network interfaces, including Bluetooth. You shouldn't have to change your [`NSNetService`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html) code for it to work, although I haven't worked with Bluetooth PANs extensively.

Comment: That was in all versions until 5. Apple has this whole tech q and a about how it's changed.

Comment: I saw that somewhere, didn't read into it too much though. Having written a couple of mDNS responders I'd consider myself familiar with Bonjour, but I've never used it over Bluetooth unfortunately :/

Comment: Thanks. I think I found a little bit of documentation and sample code in the depths of the apple site, so I'll look there. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Did you ever answer this?  Did you find documentation?  Do you happen to have links, or even keywords I could use to find what you ended up finding?